# Replace an entire json object using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to deploy a json file from one environment to another.
But i have to replace the properties of some object at the time of deployment.

For achieving this I am trying to replace the entire json object, since i have to replace most of the properties.
I am using shell script to replace the json object, but unable to do so.

below is the json file in source.

```
},
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataLakeStoreUri": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_dataLakeStoreUri')]",
                    "servicePrincipalId": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_servicePrincipalId')]",
                    "servicePrincipalKey": {
                        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                        "store": {
                            "referenceName": "eXtollokeyvault",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        },
                        "secretName": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_servicePrincipalKey_secretName')]"
                    },
                    "tenant": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_tenant')]",
                    "subscriptionId": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_subscriptionId')]",
                    "resourceGroupName": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_properties_typeProperties_resourceGroupName')]"
                },
                "connectVia": {
                    "referenceName": "coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs",
                    "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/integrationRuntimes/coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs')]",
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/eXtollokeyvault')]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore2')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataLakeStoreUri": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_dataLakeStoreUri')]",
                    "servicePrincipalId": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_servicePrincipalId')]",
                    "servicePrincipalKey": {
                        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                        "store": {
                            "referenceName": "eXtollokeyvault",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        },
                        "secretName": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_servicePrincipalKey_secretName')]"
                    },
                    "tenant": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_tenant')]",
                    "subscriptionId": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_subscriptionId')]",
                    "resourceGroupName": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore2_properties_typeProperties_resourceGroupName')]"
                },
                "connectVia": {
                    "referenceName": "coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs",
                    "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/integrationRuntimes/coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs')]",
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/eXtollokeyvault')]"
            ]
        },
```

I have to change the entire object with **name**

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]",
```

The entire object with **name** "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]",
should be like below.

```
},
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStore1_v2_properties_typeProperties_url')]"
                },
                "connectVia": {
                    "referenceName": "coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs",
                    "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/integrationRuntimes/coe-eu-ir-azu-xbs')]"
            ]
        },
```

Have to replace the entire object as above.

I have tried with powershell script by deleting the object.properties, but not able to create object as i would require.

```
$JsonData = Get-Content $json_path -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$JsonData.resources | Where{$_.name -eq "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]"} | ForEach{$_.PSObject.Properties.remove("properties")}
$JsonData.resources | Where{$_.name -eq "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStore1')]"} | ForEach{$_.PSObject.Properties.remove("dependsOn")}

$JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 50| % {[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)} | set-content $json_path
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Never edit the json directly with code: just deserialize the json to an object, modify the object (or copy the property values to a new object), then serialize it again. Editing the json directly is waiting for mistakes to happen.

Comment: yes! it was failing with error ```##[error]Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (1311554):```
Could you please provide a reference for deserializing and serializing part?

Answer (score -2):

Azure Devops is an easy way to change the linked service properties, you can create variables for each environment and then mention that in your deploy pipeline (Release pipeline)

Here's a [demo](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6510/using-azure-devops-ci-cd-to-deploy-azure-data-factory-environments/)

Comment: Hi @Antony : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !